Как двигать собранным объектом в одну сторону?

Собранный обьект и не могу двигать им в одну сторону, помогите

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
